# Passing value from visualforce to apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to pass a value from visualforce page to apex controller using **apex:param** inside the **apex:repeat** but it gives me a null value. How to make my code work? am i missing something ? Please help me.

HERE IS WHAT I'VE GOT

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:repeat value="{!ButtonsControl}" var="btnlist" id="btnsid" >

  <apex:outputText value="{!btnlist.Option_Name__c}">
        <apex:param name="LikedUserName" value="{!btnlist.Option_Name__c}" assignTo="{!actionBTN}" />
  </apex:outputText>

</apex:repeat>
```

APEX CONTROLLER

```
global with sharing class Contact_Handler_Controller {

public String actionBTN{get;set;}

public static List<Control_Option__c> getButtonsControl(){
   return [SELECT Id,Object__c,Option_Name__c FROM Control_Option__c WHERE Object__c='Contact'];
}
public Contact_Handler_Controller()
{
   system.debug('papadomzzzzzz'+actionBTN);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The constructor is called *before* your `getButtonsControl`, and so it will indeed be null. In fact, that code, by itself, doesn't have any particular purpose, because you're not using the parameter with a function call of some sort. Here'd be a typical usage:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!ButtonsControl}" var="btnlist" id="btnsid" >
  <apex:commandButton action="{!doSomething}" value="Do Something" reRender="form">
    <apex:param name="LikedUserName" value="{!btnlist.Option_Name__c}" assignTo="{!actionBTN}" />
  </apex:commandButton>
</apex:repeat>
```

This will call the function doSomething (not currently defined in your controller), and actionBTN will contain the appropriate value for that instance of the button within your action function.

Comment: but what i want is when the apex repeat is executed , the data will automatically pass to the apex controller without any action by the user.

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio You'd just assign a value directly to a variable. `apex:param` is used for passing values between Visualforce components and Apex Code. In fact, I'm not really sure what problem it is you're trying to solve; I'd suggest opening a new question to address the problem you're having (what you've attempted/what you're trying to do), rather than ask specific questions about why a particular syntax is correct or not.

Comment: You have a big point fox. Here is the scenario, I want to write a program that will display a dynamic button , that button has the status of (ON/OFF) so if button is off button style will inactive and if its on, style will be active. So to do that I have two Object First Object(**Buttons__c**...Custom field(**Button_name__c**)), is where i will add manually a dynamic button i want to display in the page. Second Object(**Button_Status__c**...Field(**Button_Name__c,Status__c**))is where the  status(ON/OFF) based.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the line of code

```
<apex:param name="LikedUserName" value="{!btnlist.Option_Name__c}" assignTo="{!actionBTN}" />
```

This should solve the problem, i believe.